# android countdown timer cancel doesn't stop the countdown

Tags: android

I'm working on my first Android app, so forgive my newbieness. The app is a countdown timer with a default starting value that I want the user to have the option of overriding.

The closest thing to success I've had is to add a button that pops up a dialog into which the user types the new value. The timer correctly uses the new value when it begins counting down, but when the timer toggle button is clicked OFF during the countdown, the timer.cancel() does not stop the numbers from ticking down. I've tried creating my own timerCancel() method in the Counter class that calls onFinish() but the numbers still keep ticking.

TIA for your help.

```
package com.mypackage.myapp;
/*
* Used tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqqP69rJVmg for countdown timer
*/

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.media.SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SprintActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DBHelper mydb ;
SharedPreferences prefs = null;

final Context context = this;

ToggleButton toggle;
ImageButton btn_editSprintValue;
TextView textViewTimer;
TextView p, c, t, s;
int iSprintDuration, iSprDefault;

private SoundPool soundPool;
private int soundID;
boolean loaded = false;
String sTitle;
String sCurrWC;
String sTarWC;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sprint);

    mydb = new DBHelper(this);

    p = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_ProjTitle);
    c = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_curr_wc);
    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_tar_wc);
    s = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_sprint_dur);
    btn_editSprintValue = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_editsprintdur);

    //show the project name and the current word count
    //First, get the record id from the
    //data bundle that's passed in as an "extra"
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        int projid = extras.getInt("id");
        if(projid>0){

            Cursor rs = mydb.getProjectData(projid);
            rs.moveToFirst();

            //now get project title, target word count, and current word count from the db
            sTitle = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.PROJECTS_COLUMN_TITLE));
            int i = rs.getInt(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.PROJECTS_COLUMN_CURR_WORDCOUNT));
            sCurrWC = String.valueOf(i);
            i = rs.getInt(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.PROJECTS_COLUMN_TARGET_WORDCOUNT));
            sTarWC = String.valueOf(i);

            if (!rs.isClosed())
            {
                rs.close();
            }

            prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
                    "com.mypackage.myapp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            iSprDefault = prefs.getInt("default_sprint_len", 45);

            //set the title to the project title
            p.setText(sTitle);

            // now set the current and target word count and sprint duration fields
            c.setText(sCurrWC);
            t.setText(sTarWC);
            s.setText(String.valueOf(iSprDefault));

        }
    }

    //set up the timer toggle button
    toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    textViewTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    iSprintDuration = 60 * 1000 * iSprDefault;

    //When user clicks the toggle, start the timer
    toggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RunTheTimerStuff(v);
        }
    });

    // Set the hardware buttons to control the music
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    // Load the sound
    soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                                   int status) {
            loaded = true;
        }
    });
    soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.finished, 1);

}

public void RunTheTimerStuff(View v){
    textViewTimer.setText("00:00:00");

    final Counter timer = new Counter(iSprintDuration,1000);

    if (((ToggleButton) v).isChecked()) {
        s.setEnabled(false);
        s.setCursorVisible(false);
        s.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        s.setClickable(false);
        timer.UpdateTimer();
        timer.start();
    } else {
        s.setEnabled(true);
        s.setCursorVisible(true);
        s.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        s.setClickable(true);
        timer.timercancel();
        textViewTimer.setText("00:00:00");
    }

}

public void onClickUpdateSprint (View view) {
    //This is where we call the dialog to get the new sprint duration
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    final EditText edittext = new EditText(context);
    edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    alert.setMessage("Select a number from 5-120 (minutes)");
    alert.setTitle("Set a sprint duration for this session");

    alert.setView(edittext);

    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //What ever you want to do with the value
            String editTextValue = edittext.getText().toString();
            int i = Integer.valueOf(editTextValue);
            iSprintDuration = 60 * 1000 * i;
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //do nothing
        }
    });

    alert.show();
}


public class Counter extends CountDownTimer{

    long millis;

    public Counter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        millis = millisInFuture;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisInFuture) {
        millis = millisInFuture;
        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
        System.out.println(hms);
        textViewTimer.setText(hms);
    }

    public void timercancel(){
        onFinish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

        textViewTimer.setText("00:00:00");
        // Getting the user sound settings
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;
        // Is the sound loaded already?
        if (loaded) {
            soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
            Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
        }

        toggle.setChecked(false);
        s.setEnabled(true);
        s.setClickable(true);
        s.setCursorVisible(true);
        s.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    }

    public void UpdateTimer() {
        millis = (long) iSprintDuration;
    }

} //end counter class


} //end activity class
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a few things.

Firstly, instantiate a new CountDownTimer as a global variable in SprintActivity, and a timeRemaining variable, which we can set to 0 for the time being. (milliseconds) as well as a variable for the starting amount.

```
 CountDownTimer timer;
 Integer timeRemaining = 0;
 Integer startingTime = 1000;
```

Now, in your RunTheTimerStuff(View v), use this instead :

```
 timeRemaining = startingTime;
 Integer countDownInterval = 1000;
 //CountDownTimer(Total Time Milliseconds, count down interval also Milliseconds)
 timer = new CountDownTimer(startingTime, countDownInterval) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timeRemaining -= countDownInterval;
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            //Do stuff here
        }
    }.start();
```

To cancel the timer anywhere in this activity, call timer.cancel();. This will stop the timer and what you're left with is the timeRemaining. For example, if it was a 20 second timer and you stopped it with one second left,time remaining should be 1000.

To add to the timer and start again, simply add onto the starting time, then call the RunTheTimerStuff(View v) again.

```
 startingTime = timeRemaning + theTimeTheyWishToAdd;
 RunTheTimerStuff(null);
```

Just make sure to reset the starting time if you decide to not add onto the current time, but to start a new one.

```
 startingTime = 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This solution doesn't make the numbers on the screen change at all. I've tried making a few adjustments, but I can't get this particular solution to work.